# SQL Server 2008 Beginner Script Question On: Delimited Strings with Substrings and case statements

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, scripting

I am trying to take a data string from one column and split it into several different columns. The question is I need to use a space (' ') as a delimiter and I'm not sure how? Also, I would need to incorporate case statements (I'm assumeing) in order to split with a substring in other areas.

Eample: Name Account 445566    0010020056893010445478008 AFD 369
I can use space as delimiter up to the point of the 001002... data string. That has to be futher broken down. Also, If I'm using space as a delimiter when I hit an area with multiple spaces how do I avoid empty columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a split table-function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(   
 @String varchar(max)
,@Delimiter char
)
RETURNS @Results table
(
 Ordinal int
,StringValue varchar(max)
)
as
begin

    set @String = isnull(@String,'')
    set @Delimiter = isnull(@Delimiter,'')

    declare
     @TempString varchar(max) = @String
    ,@Ordinal int = 0
    ,@CharIndex int = 0

    set @CharIndex = charindex(@Delimiter, @TempString)
    while @CharIndex != 0 begin     
        set @Ordinal += 1       
        insert @Results values
        (
         @Ordinal
        ,substring(@TempString, 0, @CharIndex)
        )       
        set @TempString = substring(@TempString, @CharIndex + 1, len(@TempString) - @CharIndex)     
        set @CharIndex = charindex(@Delimiter, @TempString)
    end

    if @TempString != '' begin
        set @Ordinal += 1 
        insert @Results values
        (
         @Ordinal
        ,@TempString
        )
    end

    return
end
```

Usage:

```
select
s.*
from dbo.Split('445566          0010020056893010445478008 AFD 369', ' ') as s
where s.StringValue != '' -- this condition will drop your extra spaces
```

Yields:

```
Ordinal    StringValue
1   445566
11  0010020056893010445478008
12  AFD
13  369
```

Which you can break down further if necessary.

Comment: How could I talor this function to split into rows instead of one column?

Comment: Yes, I can see how thats a problem. I do know that all the strings are 120 characters but how they should be broken up varies from string to string. Heck of a brain teaser!

Comment: @antisanity and @gbn I would like to get a better handle on T-Sql, Could you recommend a book for me? I have about two years of Sql experience but have never gotten into the Transact stuff untill now. You guys are obviously experienced and your suggestions would hold more weight in my eyes than amazon rateing. Thanks!

Comment: LOL! Actually I do have a limited background in java and C# myself. My supervisor actually had the same advice, he said that most of the books he has looked at are crap and I would do better googleing and posting problems on Stack. You guys are the experts so I'm definately going to take your advice. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you get your name from a SQL sanity check. I didn't know the term and up untill now I just thought it was a clever way of stateing "crazy"! hehe!